# Subheading for comments

Tags: discussion

We have a subheading for votes, badges, answers, and questions. Could we have it for comments as well, so that we note how many comments we have, and how many votes or flags each of them have?

Comment: Very good idea. Unfortunately, this would go against the policy of our website's creators, which is to discourage commenting in general and prevent us from using comments efficiently. They have explicitly stated this policy. Their reason is that they want to discourage discussion; in short, they want simple answers or nothing.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see your comments I suggest your user page activity tab, filtered for comments:

https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8183/ham-and-bacon?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_comments

The main function of a Q&A system is asking questions and getting answers, so there's a limit to how much we want to promote the meta-commentary of comments.

That's why

- it takes 50 rep to leave a comment
- there is no gold comment badge, only silver

for example.